# Is it possible to call a user-space callback function from kernel space in Linux (ioctl)?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, ioctl

Is it possible to expand the ioctl interface in Linux so that the user-space application can send a pointer to a function to the kernel space driver?

I'm in particular thinking of ways to handle the stream in user-controllable way but doing it in the kernel. Those operations could be attached to the kernel module but this would make development a lot easier as I wouldn't need to mess with the kernel during development.

More specifically, this would be the process:

1. Data is read by the driver to a buffer.
2. Data is handled by these user-defined functions in place.
3. Some more handling is done, possibly with some HW blocks.
4. Data is used by a user-space application.

Comment: Running user supplied code in kernel space would open a massive security hole in the system.

Comment: I know, but even if this was only for initial development it would be *very* useful.

Comment: @stsquad I don't think he wants to run user-mode code in kernel context, but rather something like calling his syscall from user code, passsing it callback handler pointer, an kernel returning to the user-mode on every call of it, so it looks just like regular callback from user-code perspective.

Comment: That's pretty much what I was thinking, j_kubik.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you can achieve what you want by having your driver provide one or more character devices (or block devices) that your user space applications opens.

Then you could use [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) ([linux journal article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8478)) for kernel->user space event communication. Ioctl or writing to the device for user space->kernel event communication. Data exchange could also be achieved by reading/writing to one or more device files.

Alternatively you can provide /proc or /sys filesystem entries or use netlink.

You might also consider [ksocket](http://ksocket.sourceforge.net/):

> Ksocket is a linux 2.6 kernel module
>   that provides bsd-style socket
>   interfaces (namely socket, bind,
>   listen, connect, accept, ...) for
>   kernel developers to facilitate their
>   network progaramming in linux kernel
>   space.
>       The interfaces ksocket presents are much the same as their equivalent
>   in glibc, so even new developers for
>   kernel space will have no barrier in
>   developing kernel network-related
>   programms.

Comment: Well, obviously I could send the data back, but if we talk about high-speed communication (like, audio data) that would facilitate a lot of data being copied all over the place...

Answer (score 3):

I think you're asking for a square circle: if the kernel were to just execute your "userland" function directly, it wouldn't be "userland" but rather a homebrew loadable module system.  I assume that what you *really* want is a way to figure out what to do to make it all work without crashing your PC every time you make a mistake.  Maybe you could abuse signal handlers as the means of "callback", but I'm too rusty to point out how you'd get *back* to the kernel as if by a function call return.  The problem here is that in any userland->kernel context switch, the kernel starts with a fresh stack, so the return address is long gone.  How about if you combine a signal handler with mmap'ing /dev/mem, and let your userland pseudodriver poke the kernel-mode driver's data structures directly?  But then you're back to rebooting when you make a mistake, unless you figure out how to mmap *only* your driver's data structures?  Other repurposeable mechanisms might be STREAMS and TTY line disciplines; I think these confer some sort of transmogrifying ability.  Of course none of this is a good idea as a permanent solution!

Comment: I can always run the development system in a virtual machine, so crashing isn't really the issue here.

Answer (score 2):

Your use case keeps mentioning data.

Maybe what you want to do is share memory between the kernel and a user process. You could put data and/or commands into the shared memory, and the process/kernel code on the other side could read it and do whatever. The get_user_pages_fast() call can make a process's memory accessible to the kernel, even when the process is not currently running.