# How to send Notification from Kernel to user space application using SYSFS

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, linux-device-driver, sample, userspace

I'm working in an USB ACM driver, "where i need to send notification from kernel space to user space application for invoking a call back function". I'm not much aware of using kernel to user interfaces in code. how well can sysfs help for this scenario. Please send some sample code to use sysfs so that I'll get an idea to implement in my code. I could not find it anywhere. Also pls tell anyother easy way to achieve kernel to user space notification.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The second question in "Related" list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689975/is-it-possible-to-call-a-user-space-callback-function-from-kernel-space-in-linux. It should help you in making your question more concrete.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to create a sysfs interface to your kernel driver that userspace can access. Each sysfs attribute if created with the correct properties can be read like a file from userspace. You can then use the poll function from userspace to poll for an action on that file. To trigger this action from Kernel space, you can use the `sysfs_notify` function on your attribute and it will cause your userspace code to wake up. Here is how I would do it

Kernel
 1. Create Kobject or attach an attribute to a previous kobject
 2. When you want to signal userspace call sysfs_notify on the kobject and attribute

Userspace

1. Create a new thread that will block while waiting for the sysfs_notify
2. Open the sysfs attribute from this thread
3. poll the attribute, once sysfs_notify from the kernel is called it will unblock your poll
4. call your event handling function

Comment: Note that sysfs notify cannot be called from an interrupt context, so if your event is an interrupt, you need to create some type of deferred work. You can also use the sysfs_dirent interface which will take care of the deferred work for you

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative would be to use [eventfd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html). You create eventfd, pass the integer file descriptor to kernel space (e.g. through sysfs, or ioctl), then convert the file descriptor you got from user space to eventfd_ctx in kernel space. This is it - you have your notification channel.

User space

```
#include <sys/eventfd.h>

int efd = eventfd(0, 0);
// pass 'efd' to kernel space
```

Kernel space

```
#include <linux/eventfd.h>

// Set up
int efd = /* get from user space - sysfs/ioctl/write/... */;
struct eventfd_ctx* efd_ctx = eventfd_ctx_fdget(efd);

// Signal user space
eventfd_signal(efd_ctx, 1);

// Tear down
eventfd_ctx_put(efd_ctx);
```